# Wordpress Anchor links

Tags: html, wordpress

This is my first time making a custom WordPress website. The website is mostly one page except for the posts that take you to a single.php page. From the single.php page I figured out that if I add this code:

```
<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>
```

to the logo I'm able to go back to the home page. However, my menu links are anchor links that are located in the home page. I haven't figured out how to properly link these menu links so they'll go to the right place in the home page.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
<a href="../index.php?page_id=#id">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding these menu items in the Admin, and if the sections on your page have `id` attributes, you can change the link to them using the following structure:

```
#id-of-section
```

...or, using a regular link:

```
<a href="#id-of-section">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the menu items were not added in the admin, they are hard coded.

Comment: The the regular link format I posted is what you need to do.